# How to modify the style of legends in tooltips without using a formatter

Tags: web, echarts, apache-echarts

I can not find a way to modify the default style of legends which in tooltip.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2qC.png)

I can edit it by using formatter, but it is complex for me when i use multiple ecahrts, so i wanna a easy way to edit it directly

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip spawns a div element. You could try setting formatter to an empty string and modify the div directly.

[image: div element]